# No reminders on Windows Mobile 6.1

Tags: windows-mobile, reminder, windows-mobile-6

After I had installed and uninstalled Slovoed Merriam Webster dictionary, my reminders stopped working.

I've clened the whole system with SKTools to no avail. All check-boxes is System>Personal>Notifications are checked.

Is there something in registry I can check/fix?

Regards,

Comment: Questions about mobile phones are off topic on Super User, sorry

Comment: What's StackExchange site they are supposed to be ontopic?

Comment: At the moment there is no site for Windows Mobile questions. There is Android though.

Comment: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/20757/windows-phone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change timezone to visiting then back to home. For me it's worked.